# Screen watermark not worked on macOS 12.4, but work fine before macOS 12.4

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nswindow, macos-system-extension

I developed a screen watermarking program that worked fine before macOS 12.4. After upgrading to 12.4, "System Extension Blocked" pop-up cann't be click, but the other window is ok. the sample code like this

```
NSScreen *screen = [NSScreen screens][0];

CGFloat windowWidth = screen.frame.size.width;
CGFloat windowHeight = screen.frame.size.height;
CGFloat x = screen.frame.origin.x;
CGFloat y = screen.frame.origin.y;

MyView* view = [[MyView alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight)];

NSWindow* window = [[NSPanel alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight)
                                              styleMask: NSWindowStyleMaskBorderless | NSWindowStyleMaskNonactivatingPanel
                                                backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                                  defer:NO];
[window setOpaque:NO];
[window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
[window setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces | NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary];
[window setIgnoresMouseEvents:YES];
[window setHasShadow:NO];
[window setLevel:NSScreenSaverWindowLevel];
[window setContentView:views];

[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

and draw in MyView

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSRect screen = [self bounds];

    int SW = screen.size.width;
    int SH = screen.size.height;

    [[NSColor clearColor] set];

    NSRectFill(screen);

    NSString * strH= @"watermark test.";

    NSMutableDictionary *md = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [md setObject:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Times" size:80] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

    [strH drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(SH*0.5, SH*0.5) withAttributes:md];

    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

This code is worked fine from macOS 11.0 to macOS 12.3, Could anybody tell me how to adapt to macOS 12.4 for my code.
I have ask on Apple forums, but nobody reply. [This is the link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/707591)

Comment: What specifically is not working? (What worked before, what still works now, what doesn't? Your point about system extensions, is that purely about the dialog or have you implemented a system extension for this?)

Comment: only the dialog cann't be close, click the button "OK" or "Open Security Preferences", the dialog not response.   but before 12.4, this dialog work fine